# getting all chars before space in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am trying to get all chars before the space:

```
SUBSTRING(reporttime,1,CHARINDEX(reporttime,' ',1))
```

but it is not working. please help!

example data:

```
7/8/2010 11:47 AM
7/8/2010 10:55 AM
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Select Substring( MyTextColumn, 1, CharIndex( ' ', MyTextColumn ) - 1)
```

Actually, if these are datetime values, then there is a better way:

```
Select Cast(DateDiff(d, 0, MyDateColumn) As datetime)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the Date from a DateTime value, the best line of code I've found to strip the time value & modified to your requirements is:

```
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), reporttime, 103)
```

This will display 07/08/2010.